# Is passphrase (the 25th word) using open source algorithms? Can I recover the passphrase on any hardware wallets?

Tags: private-key, hardware-wallet, passphrase, ledger-hardware-wallet

Many hardware wallets provide the passphrase function that allows you to protect your assets even if your 24 seed phrases are compromised. But I worry that the different companies use different passphrase algorithms. Let's say I store my Bitcoin on Ledger using 24 words + passphrase and 10 years later, Ledger company does not exist. Can I recover my wallet to other hardware wallets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most wallets use the same algorithm, as it is an open standard, [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).

A notable exception is [Electrum](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html), which uses a similar, but slightly different mechanism. This is publicly documented and can be reproduced by others.